# click on image and change a text

Tags: javascript, html

U have 2 images on a page and a textbox (php)

When u click on the image i want to change the text.

I am a starter, please sent a code that isn't to hard to understand.

```
<body>
    <img src="bier1.jpg" alt="u mad" onclick= "">
    <img src="bier2.jpg" alt="u mad" onclick= ""><br>

    <form>
    <input type="text" name="Example"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You want to do it using PHP only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are I'm right that you want to change the text of the Textbox? If yes here's the code:

```
    <body>
        <img src="bier1.jpg" alt="u mad" onclick= "document.forms[0].elements['Example'].value = 'Image 1'">
        <img src="bier2.jpg" alt="u mad" onclick= "document.forms[0].elements['Example'].value = 'Image 2'"><br>

        <form>
        <input type="text" name="Example"/>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first add `id` to the text field:

```
<input type="text" name="Example" id="myTextBox" />
```

Then you can do such thing:

```
<img src="bier1.jpg" alt="u mad" onclick="document.getElementById('myTextBox').value = this.alt;" />
<img src="bier2.jpg" alt="u mad" onclick="document.getElementById('myTextBox').value = this.alt;" />
```

This is not very elegant though, you have it applied to all images without having to change the markup, have such JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oTextbox = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
    for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        document.images[i].onclick = function() {
            oTextbox.value = this.alt;
        };
    }
};
```

[Live test case of above code](http://jsfiddle.net/aweMK/).

You can also have the above code work only for certain images by applying a class to those images you want "clickable", for example:

```
<img src="bier1.jpg" alt="u mad" />
<img class="clickable" src="bier2.jpg" alt="u mad 2" />
```

To have only the second cause the textbox to change, have such code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oTextbox = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
    for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        var image = document.images[i];
        if (image.className === "clickable" || image.className.indexOf("clickable ") >= 0 || image.className.indexOf(" clickable") >= 0) {
            image.onclick = function() {
                oTextbox.value = this.alt;
            };
        }
    }
};​
```

[Updated fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/aweMK/1/).

Comment: No need to add an id to the field, this can easily be done with just a name, javascript will return an array of elements with that name, however if it is the only one on the page it can be selected easily as the 0 index of the array.

Comment: @Jon not if the textbox is independent i.e. not part of a form and looks like that's the case here. Can't see anything wrong with adding `id`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with using id but its not needed.  Why does it need to be part of a form to search by name? Why cant you use document.getElementsByName("Example"); This will return an array of elements in the dom that have the name Example.  From his code there is only a single such occurance so getting the first element of the array will return the input element.

Comment: @Jon good point, I was thinking of the other answer with `document.forms[0].elements['Example']`. Anyway why work with arrays and assume you have only one? Guess it's more personal flavor though.

Comment: yeah I agree, I would generally use ids but then I have had plenty of situations where I am able to modify javascript code but can not do anything to the html code.  This would put me in a situation where I would be unable to add an id in and would have to work with what I am given, in this case a name.

However I would agree that using an id would be better.

Comment: is it possible to change two text fields in single click? like if i click on an image, it should change the text in two text boxes..

Comment: @ManoHaran of course, after the line `oTextbox.value = this.alt;` add another line, setting the desired value to the desired second textbox.

Comment: <img src="images/w1.jpg" alt="mytext" onclick="document.getElementById('txtbx').value = this.alt; , document.getElementById('txtbx2').value = this.alt; " /> But it didnt work..

Comment: @Mano you have a comma in the `onclick`, it should not be there. Only the ";" between commands.

Comment: that worked thanks.. and other thing which is not working for me is, i have two buttons like one way and return. when page loads it directly lands on one way and when i click the button below it changes the text. but when i click return and click the button its not changing the text..

Comment: sorry.. i made a mistake with id.. that worked.. thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Javascript, I prefer to give javascript code using [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/), so please do a quick Google search on [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //You need to bind click events to your images and probably
        $("img.has-message").click(function(){
            var msg = $(this).attr("data-msg");
            //get the message from that particular image
            $("#text_box_id").attr("value",msg);
            //changes the value of the text box to display the message
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

So you place this code in the `<head></head>` tag of your page

This code will work perfectly assuming you could change your HTML to look like so:

```
<body>
    <img src="bier1.jpg" alt="u mad" class="has-message" data-msg="message to be displayed when the image is clicked">
    <img src="bier2.jpg" alt="u mad" class="has-message" data-msg="message to be displayed when the image is clicked"><br>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="text_box_id" name="Example"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Please remember that jQuery needs to have been included on your page for the above to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing they mean the page is served as a php page.  I would do this purely in javascript.  In pseudo code I would do the following.

1. Create function in javascript
2. Function looks up input using name
3. Function sets the text of the input to whatever you like (this could be based on which image was clicked

Id deffinately suggest looking at w3schools website which will give you lots of simple examples to get you started.

Also start basic and work your way up, if you cant get it all working at once, do it bit by bit, get your onclick to alert when you click it, then try setting the text once you knwo your onclicks are working.