# Changing text by clicking an image

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I am a javascript noob.

I want clicking on the images to change the text in a span

What I have so far:

Image:

```
    <img src="image.png" onclick="document.span[0].elements['videoTitle'].value = 'My Text'" />
```

Span:

```
    <span name="videoTitle"><strong>My Initial Text</strong></span>
```

I dont know what should follow "document." and I assume i need javascript in the header or something?

I was referencing this post: [click on image and change a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188841/click-on-image-and-change-a-text)

I have no idea what I'm doing here. I don't understand js,  I'm a designer!

Comment: I was also having problems because I realized the text I wanted to change it to had an apostrophe, so it was screwing up the code- so I used &lsquo; instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:-

```
 document.getElementsByName('videoTitle')[0] // assuming this is the first element with  
                                             //the name `videoTitle`
.getElementsByTagName('strong')[0]
 .innerHTML = 'My Text'
```

SO it will be

```
<span name="videoTitle"><strong>My Initial Text</strong></span>
<img src="image.png" onclick="document.getElementsByName('videoTitle')[0].getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHTML = 'My Text'" />
This is native old way and is supported in all browsers.
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XfrG3/)

Answer (score 0):

Span's do not have value properties.  You need to use innerHTML in this case, like so:

```
<img src="image.png" onclick="document.getElementsByName('videoTitle')[0].getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHTML = 'My Text'" />
```

This will change the text of the first element with name videoTitle on your page.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/duffmaster33/7j59H/

Answer (score -1):

I recommend do something like this:

```
<img src="image.png" onclick="document.getElementsByName('videoTitle')[0].getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHtml= 'My Text'" />
```

or

```
<img src="image.png" onclick="myFunc()" />
<script>
function myFunc(){
document.getElementsByName('videoTitle')[0].getElementsByTagName('strong')[0].innerHtml="my text";
}
</script>
```

I also advice to give the span an id and select it by ID